# How to connect two classes of two different packages?

Tags: java

suppose Mypoint class is in package A and Mycircle class in package B.How can I connect them so I can use the properties of Mypoint in Mycircle?

Comment: Are both packages in the same project? If so, then you should be able to link them fine (the public keyword can be accessed from anywhere)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could import the packages by putting this above your class declaration

```
import packageA.Mypoint;
```

or

```
import packageB.MyCircle;
```

Also, since a circle is made up of points, you could use inheritance, so all Mypoint methods will be available to objects created from the Mycircle class

```
public class Mycircle extends Mypoint
```

Comment: I haven't learnt about inheritance yet.thanks for the info anyway!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this task

1. Using Inheritance
2. Making Objects of Class A in Class B or vice versa and call the functions of the Class A or Class B using the respective Object created.
3. By Making the class A or Class B Public (if both are in different packages)

Answer (score 0):

You need to import your first package to your second.

```
    import packageA.Mypoint;
```